# Use 2nd dataframe to rename columns in R that are present in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Let me create an example first and then explain the question:

```
old_names <- c("FG%", "Dist.", "2P", "0-3", "3-10", "10-16")
new_names <- c("FG%", "Dist", "2P_Freq", "0_3_Freq", "3_10_Freq", "10_16_Freq")

dput(mydf)
structure(list(`FG%` = c(0.451, 0.454, 0.444, 0.444, 0.442), 
`2P` = c(0.691, 0.607, 0.629, 0.744, 0.665), `0-3` = c(0.331, 
0.296, 0.309, 0.28, 0.282), `10-16` = c(0.092, 0.071, 0.077, 
0.117, 0.099)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

mydf
    FG%    2P   0-3 10-16
1 0.451 0.691 0.331 0.092
2 0.454 0.607 0.296 0.071
3 0.444 0.629 0.309 0.077
4 0.444 0.744 0.280 0.117
5 0.442 0.665 0.282 0.099
```

I have a dataframe `mydf` that has a varying number of columns. I am aware of the entire possible set of current column names `old_names`, and when they are present in the dataframe, I would like to replace them with the value at the same index in `new_names`. In the example above, 4 of the 6 columns are present, and I need them renamed to the new_names values.

A solution that uses one or more of dplyr's rename, rename_at, rename_if, rename_all would be particularly useful, as I try to use dplyr as much as I can for this type of data manip. I have tried a few attempts on this with no luck.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
names(mydf) = new_names[old_names %in% names(mydf)]
```